# Can C++'s class variables be initialized without a constructor like in Java?

Tags: java, c++, constructor

In Java I could create a class and initialize a variable without a constructor:

```
public class Foo {
private int x = 1;
public getx() {
    return x;
    }
}
```

But in c++, to accomplish the same thing, the only way I know how is to do this:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Foo()
    {
        x = 1;
    }
    getx()
    {
        return x;
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you try it? Newer versions of GCC and MSVC will accept `int x = 1;` by default, and Clang explicitly calls out turning on C++11 support.

Comment: In fact, the [CppCoreGuidelines recommends in-class initializers](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c48-prefer-in-class-initializers-to-member-initializers-in-constructors-for-constant-initializers) for default values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11 you can do this. In other words, this works pretty well:

```
class Foo
{
    int x = 1;
public:
    int getX() { return x;}
};
```